# Eclipse plugin for hadoop

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hadoop

I have a problem when compiling eclipse plugin this is the error that I get

```
/usr/local/hadoop/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin$ ant
Buildfile: /usr/local/hadoop/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/hadoop/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.xml:22: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/hadoop/src/contrib/build-contrib.xml:43: Element type "property" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Total time: 0 seconds
```

and modified lines are these

```
41:  <!--modificacion de hadoop-->
42:  <!-- Property added for compiling eclipse plugin -->
43:  <property name="src.eclipse"  location="${root}/usr/lib/eclipse"/> 
44:  <!--cerrado-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed a tutorial to create this plug-in ?
If you modify only build.xml I don't think it will work. Here is what I used and worked for me:

Edit build­contrib.xml
(the lines under depends on your hadoop's version, I tried all this with a 1.2.1 hadoop)

```
<property name="version" value="1.2.1" />

<property name="eclipse.home" value="/path/to/eclipse/home" />
```

Edit and add the following lines in build.properties :

```
eclipse.home=/path/to/eclipse/home

version=1.2.1

commons­cli.version=1.2

commons­configuration.version=1.6

commons­httpclient.version=3.0.1

commons­lang.version=2.4

jackson­core­asl.version=1.8.8

jackson­mapper­asl.version=1.8.8
```

in META­INF/MANIFEST.MF :

```
Bundle­ClassPath: classes/,

lib/hadoop­core.jar,

lib/commons­cli­1.2.jar,

lib/commons­configuration­1.6.jar,

lib/jackson­core­asl­1.8.8.jar,

lib/commons­httpclient­3.0.1.jar,

lib/jackson­mapper­asl­1.8.8.jar,

lib/commons­lang­2.4.jar
```

in build.xml, add after  :

```
<fileset dir="${hadoop.root}">

      <include name="*.jar" />

</fileset>
```

Finally, execute ant jar and add the generated plug in to eclipse.